# How can I populate memcached automatically everytime I restart my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I want to be able to put about 3k "documents" into memcached each time I restart my rails application, does anyone know how I could go about doing this?

The documents are search result pointers and rarely change.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you add a new  initializer file: `config/initializers/memcached_data.rb`
And put the instructions needed to load the data in memcached there in that file.